# What arguments should be passed to (wekaCategoricalData)?

Tags: matlab, weka, feature-selection

I am trying to use the Information Gain algorithm available in [here](http://featureselection.asu.edu/software.php), which is implemented in Matlab and it uses Weka java classes. However, I get the following problem when trying to run the code:

```
Undefined function 'wekaCategoricalData' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

The code line which generates the error is this:

```
t.buildEvaluator(wekaCategoricalData(X, SY2MY(Y)));
```

SY2MY is just a transformation function and it is described [here](http://featureselection.asu.edu/featureselection_techreport.pdf).

The algorithm apparently expects an argument of the type (spider data object), which I have no idea what it is exactly. There appears to be something wrong with the number of the arguments sent as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you add the Weka jar-file to the class path `javaaddpath`?

Comment: ok there is a `load_fspackage.m` script you are supposed to run once you installed the "Feature Selection Package". This should setup the MATLAB path and add the required JAR-files to classpath (including Weka). This is described in the 'Readme' file

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem has now been solved. The problem occurred because the package was not even installed! I was only using javaaddpath to add weka classes. Anyway, once again, thank you very much.

Comment: Could you please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the readme file included with the [package](http://featureselection.asu.edu/downloadpackage.php), you need to run the `load_fspackage.m` script on initial installation of the "Feature Selection Package".

This will setup various M-file on the MATLAB path, as well as add the required Weka JAR-file to the Java classpath.